# Can I average a series of non-linear relationships?

Tags: nonlinear-system, average

Is it mathematically valid to average a series of non-linear relationships? With regard to a reel of paper, I have a series of reel diameters and their associated linear feet.

Can I divide each diameter by its associated linear feet, and then average the resulting ratio's? And finally divide 60" (the target diameter) by the resulting average of ratios to get an  accurate average linear feet for a 60" diameter reel of paper?

For Example:

Diameter,   Ln Ft,    Dia/LnFT;

60,        12235,   0.004903964;

60,        12231,   0.004905568;

60,        12222,   0.00490918;

60.5,      12071,   0.005012012;

58.7,      11641,   0.005042522;

60.5,      12271,   0.004930324;

Average Dia/LnFT = 0.004950595

60/average =    12119.75533

Comment: Does the roll have a central spindle around which the paper is wound and if so is it fair to assume they are all the same? I think better to average the implied thickness of the paper.

Comment: we can assume the spool in the center is the same diameter

Answer (score 0):

If the paper is of length $L$ and spool is of radius $a$ and whole roll radius $b$ then the thickness of the paper is  $d=\frac{\pi(b^2-a^2)}{L}$. Average the thicknesses and get the length from $L=\frac{\pi(3600-a^2)}{average(d)}$.